# Jettison JSON/java , send list of string with json request

Tags: java, json, geojson, jettison

I am creating `JSON` object and send over the network , like

```
 org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject json = new org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject();
                json.put("id", "15");
                json.put("code", "secret");
                json.put("type", "new type");
```

Also I have links of photos what I want to put into this `JSON`

```
my links like http://box.com/images/photo.jpg,http://box.com/images/photo1.jpg
http://box.com/images/photo2.jpg, http://box.com/images/photo3.jpg
As I understand I must have some list/array and put like
json.put("images", links)
```

How to do it, put and parse... I need one key, and list of values.
Is `JSON` array is useful for this?

Thanks

Comment: Minor comment/question: why are you using Jettison here? It's a mapping tool for converting between XML and JSON. `JSONObject` comes from org.json library, although better JSON lib choices include GSON and Jackson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. JSONArray is what you need.

```
    List <String> links = getLinks();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (String link : links)
            array.put(link);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    //put id, code, type...
    obj.put("images", array);
```

Comment: I think you can skip the `for` loop there and just do `array.put(links)`

Comment: Yep, you're right: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `JSONArray` class.

http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html

You'll create a `JSONArray` and use that in your `put` command.